# How to get nUnit test report after TFS 2015 build?

Tags: tfs, nunit

Good day.

I have a TFS build and a Visual Studio Test step there. All test are run, but I can't get detailed info about them, only quantity, passed\failed\others, run duration.

Also, I see "Outcome: Failed" and "This build doesn't have test results for the outcome you've selected".

How to configure this outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly use the build-in outcome to analysis the detail test result.

You need to run the **Publish Test Result** task. First generate an XML file  which contains the results. And then use the publish results step and pointing to that file so that the test results will show up in the build output.

[image]

More details about how to use this, please refer this similar tutorial with xUnit test: [Execute and publish xUnit Tests results with .NET Core and VSTS](http://fluentbytes.com/execute-and-publish-xunit-tests-results-with-net-core-and-vsts/)

***Note:*** For now VSTS/TFS does not support **NUnit3** format. *Source Link:* [Support NUnit2 format](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/15864978-nunit-3-results-format-does-not-appear-to-be-suppo)